# How can i select facebook user friends in facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am new in facebook application. now i am working on facebook application and i want some effect like in facebook when we go in our profile and on status update we can see one facility like who are with you? means we can tag our facebook friend at the place where we are at that time. i want this effect in my facebook application, so i can tag my friend at where am i? i that any api for fetch our facebook friend and tag them?
i tried to get friend but i only display it i can not select them.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can create a tag on the photo by issuing an HTTP POST request to the tags connection, PHOTO_ID/tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i do not tag my friends on photo. i want some effect like, user is at place with abc and cde. here user is facebook user and abc and cde are his friends. i want this type of taging for perticular place.

Comment: Did you try with  CHECKIN_ID in place of PHOTO_ID. I don't find any specific thing like tagging to checkins for now in the facebook api. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/